# Connection Time Outs, is it ever normal?

Tags: internet-connection, cable-modem

I have a wired connection which has periodic timeouts. These time-outs are really getting frustrating when trying to do any sort of live connection as it causes lag and sometimes a complete service disconnect. I have been running a PC directly wired to the modem over-night (8 hours) for the past few nights. Each time I receive about 40 time-outs. So far, none of these have been back-to-back. So, my question is, is this normal? Is there any number of time-outs that I as a customer of an ISP should expect or be okay with? Is 40 in 8 hours within this number?

The IP I am pinging is my first hop, which is Road Runner's local network.

Comment: Have you replaced everything on your side? If not, you'll probably have to start there before most/all ISPs will bother.  But unless they guaranty 24/7 uptime on your connection, they'll just say "it happens".  How are you getting these measurements?  Just from running ping?  What command options did you use when running ping?  Did you run a parallel ping process to another computer on the LAN for comparison?  Are these 40 just single packet time-outs (over 8 hours)?  Also, "Normal" is subjective.

Comment: Is this DSL? If so, the problem is usually a missing DSL filter. It's easy to forget about one on an alarm system or satellite TV receiver or to move a cordless phone base station without moving the DSL filter. Unless you have a whole house splitter at the point of entry, you need a DSL filter on every device connected to your phone line or you'll get frequent disconnects.

Comment: This is NOT DSL it is cable. As far as replacing, I have tried various ethernet wires, none of this has helped. Yes the 40 are single packet time-outs and no I didn't run a parallel ping to another computer. The modem only has one port, so I have no way of doing this. I am doing this due to time-outs I have noticed while connected to my router, I have switched routers and the problem remains. Now I am looking to see what I can do, if anything, with my ISP, or if there is anything else that could be my fault. I am also running tests with the router to see how they compare.

Comment: I think the problem lies on the other side of your modem, which means your ISP.

Comment: This morning I woke up after running the router for 8 hours. It had 42 losses, two of which were back-to-back. Other than the two that were back-to-back, this sounds very similar to the modem's own issues. If this were the ISP, what could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would confirm it is router, not a fault on your PC or network card. Can you try a ping one night to your router, the following to an external IP (such as 8.8.8.8 which is the Google DNS).

Either way, I would contact your ISP and let them know what you're experiencing and see what they say.

Comment: It happens to all computers on the network at the same so I am sure that it is not a PC or network card issue. Will run further tests this weekend. I am mainly looking to find out what level of timeouts are 'normal' if any at all. I know you never want a timeout ... but do they all do it on occasion? If so, at what rate?